# How to set mono profiling for heapshot for 2 hours

Tags: mono

Requirement is like monitoring mono in terms of performance testing. 
In our project we have executed test case for 2 hours and wnats to monitor mono for 2 hours.
So my question is: how to set heapshot profiling level for 2 hour.

I have tried by putting command below:

> mono --profile=log:heapshot,heapshot=120000ms,output=MessageQueuing.out  /usr/lib/xstream/Virtustream.Services.MessageQueuing.exe
>   but output file is not expected.

This output file showing similar data what we have seen for 5 mins of execution.
In short above command don't work for me

As I am quite new to this mono profiler could you guys please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 issues here:

1. For 2 hours between heapshots you should use 7200000ms, not 120000ms (which is 120 seconds) (1000*60*60*2=7200000)
2. The options to the log-profiler have heapshot stated twice, here is a line that works for me (but generates more than heapshots, even though I am trying not to)

   ```
   mono ---profile=log:noalloc,nocalls,heapshot=7200000ms,calldepth=0,time=fast,maxframes=0,output=-output.mlpd,zip Foo.exe
   ```

Beware, that the mprof-report is very sensitive to the order of arguments. I don't understad that as-is. I always use `--reports` before `--trace` and the input file (in the case above `output.mlpd`) last

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid the extra data in the output?